# Transport scheme NOT recognized: [nsp]

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am trying to connect to a **SoftwareAg's Universal Messaging** queue in a Spring application. This is my `Config` class.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory receiverActiveMQConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();

        var properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.pcbsys.nirvana.nSpace.NirvanaContextFactory");
        properties.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "nsp://localhost:9200");
        activeMQConnectionFactory.buildFromProperties(properties);

        return activeMQConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        var factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(receiverActiveMQConnectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency("3-10");
        return factory;
    }

}
```

This is the part of my pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.pcbsys.nirvana</groupId>
    <artifactId>nClient</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.pcbsys.nirvana</groupId>
    <artifactId>nJMS</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

However, I get the following exception when I try to connect to the queue:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [nsp]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:311) ~[spring-jms-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:185) ~[spring-jms-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:507) ~[spring-jms-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584) ~[spring-jms-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:661) ~[spring-jms-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at id.mandiri.co.id.um.Main.lambda$runner$0(Main.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [nsp]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:333) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:346) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:304) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:244) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196) ~[spring-jms-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:494) ~[spring-jms-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [nsp]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:28) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:185) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.connect(TransportFactory.java:64) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:331) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not find factory class for resource: META-INF/services/org/apache/activemq/transport/nsp
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder$StandaloneObjectFactory.loadProperties(FactoryFinder.java:98) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder$StandaloneObjectFactory.create(FactoryFinder.java:60) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:148) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:182) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

It says [here](http://tech.forums.softwareag.com/techjforum/posts/list/69162.page#236388):

> UM can be used with Spring. In general, the Spring XML that works for ActiveMQ should work for UM with only the connection factory class and URL changed accordingly.

What am I missing?

**Edit**:

```java
var properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.pcbsys.nirvana.nSpace.NirvanaContextFactory");
properties.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "nsp://localhost:9200");

Context ctx = new InitialContext(properties);
return (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("local_um"); // THIS?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it. This is what worked for me:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        var factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency("3-10");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory() {
        final CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(200);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory((ConnectionFactory) jndiObjectFactoryBean().getObject());

        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JndiTemplate jndiTemplate() {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.pcbsys.nirvana.nSpace.NirvanaContextFactory");
        properties.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "nsp://local-dev:9200");

        final JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
        jndiTemplate.setEnvironment(properties);

        return jndiTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean() {
        final JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate());
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName("jndi_key");
        return jndiObjectFactoryBean;
    }

}
```

I hope it helps someone. Don't forget to add `nClient.jar` and `nJMS.jar` to your classpath. You can find them in the UM install `lib` directory.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, the link you cited states:

> In general, the Spring XML that works for ActiveMQ should work for UM with only the **connection factory class** and URL changed accordingly. [emphasis mine]

However, you *haven't* changed the connection factory class. The method `receiverActiveMQConnectionFactory` is returning an instance of `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` which is wrong. Furthermore, that method is using `ActiveMQConnectionFactory.buildFromProperties()` with *UM properties* which is why you're getting the `java.io.IOException`. You can't mix these two implementations together.

There probably is a way to simply instantiate the UM connection factory implementation (similar to what is possible with the ActiveMQ connection factory implementation), but I think you'd probably have to consult the UM developer guide for that information.

That said, JNDI *is* the recommended way to get references to admin objects (i.e. connection factories and destinations) so that your JMS applications are portable between providers. Therefore, I recommend you simply use that.

Comment: Thank you very kindly for the quick response. This is my first time working with JMS and UM. Can you edit the implementation with the necessary changes?

Comment: I've never worked with UM either, but I am a developer on ActiveMQ which is how I know you can't mix these two things together like you were trying to do. I looked around the web for the information you want, but it seems a lot of the UM documentation is locked behind a paywall. I suppose that's to be expected from closed-source software. It's not nearly as friendly to developers as most open-source alternatives.

Comment: I tried changing the implementation to not to use ActiveMQ. Instead, I'm using a plain JMS `ConnectionFactory`. See Edit. What is  `local_um` argument being passed to `ctx.lookup("local_um");` ?

Comment: In that bit of code `local_um` is the name of the JMS connection factory you're looking up in JNDI.

Comment: Is there a way to get an instance of `ConnectionFactory` without using JNDI?

Comment: I updated my answer with some additional details. I hope that helps.

Comment: Turns out I was using the wrong JNDI lookup key. Thanks for your responses. Much obliged. I will add my answer.